# setPropertiesToFetch doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm trying to use setPropertiesToFetch in my fetch request to limit the data that is retrieved from my store, but it seems to have no effect. When I use it and display the object returned into the console, I can see all my properties are there. The same data is displayed whether I set the properties or not. All the relationships display as faults, but all the data for the attributes is there.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"myAttrib"], nil]];
```

The fetch seems to return the same data per object with or without that last line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impression I had (from what the Apple engineers have said) was that the data would be faulted in for the non-fetched properties as soon as you used the accessors for that property.  It may be that in generating the description of the NSManagedObject, these accessors are being used for each property, causing the data to be faulted in right before the string describing the objects is generated.

You could try using the Core Data Faults and / or Core Data Cache Misses instruments (in the simulator) to see when the faults actually occur.  If they happen right before you print out the managed objects, that would seem to support my guess above.

Comment: Yeah I had actually thought that. But as relationship faults were being shown I thought the description would show attribute faults. Interesting, I'll have a look into that! Thanks!

Comment: I have a quick question. For some reason it is not allowing to-many relationships, only attributes and 1-1 relationships. Is this correct or an I hitting some kind of error? I'm getting:
`Invalid to many relationship...passed to setPropertiesToFetch:`

Comment: From the documentation on -setPropertiesToFetch: "The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one relationships, or expressions."  I think for to-many relationships, they recommend using -setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry, I looked at the docs for ages trying to figure it out and I can't believe I didn't see that part! Thought my docs were out of date but turns out I was just not paying enough attention! Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

The Special Considerations section of the documentation for [setPropertiesToFetch:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setPropertiesToFetch%3a) says

> This value is only used if resultType is set to NSDictionaryResultType.

Your code snippet isn't setting the resultType. Perhaps you meant to use setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:?

Answer (score 0):

try **setReturnsDistinctResults:YES**

*from the apple docs:*

setReturnsDistinctResults:

Sets whether the request should return only distinct values for the fields specified by propertiesToFetch.

- (void)setReturnsDistinctResults:(BOOL)values

Parameters
values
If YES, the request returns only distinct values for the fields specified by propertiesToFetch.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way of using `setPropertiesToFetch`

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType]; // Remember to setResultType
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"age", nil]]; 
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                               error:nil];

NSArray *nameArray = [results valueForKey:@"name"];
NSArray *ageArray = [results valueForKey:@"age"];
```

**results** is not an array of **Person objects**, but an array of **Dictionary**. You can access the Dictionaries inside like this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [results[0] valueForKey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [results[0] valueForKey:@"age"]);
```

If you only want to work with Model object (which CoreData fetches all properties/attribues of the entity), you can design your Model with Person and PersonDetail (which holds detail information about a person). This way

> - You can perform fetchRequest and get an array of Person objects
> - When accessing aPerson.detail (detail is a one-to-one relation with PersonDetail), CoreData will perform faulting for you